# How do I get my output to contain the spaces I need?

Tags: java, loops, char, spacing

I have to capitalize the first letter in every word passed into the string. My output is doing that capitalization, but it's not maintaining the format of the original output. For example, string input is "hello world", my output is "HelloWorld", and my desired output should be "Hello World."

I've tried to add spaces where I can throughout the code but nothing works. I think the problem is that when I use toCharArray, it gives me an output with no spaces? So my concatenation result is adding everything in one swoop, versus each word separately?

Or I thought that my code was using string concatenation with my result, and it's not being separated because I have both words going into the same variable.

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.io.*;

    class Main {  
      public static String LetterCapitalize(String str) { 

        // code goes here   
        String[] word = str.split(" ");
        String result = "";


        for(int i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {

            char[] charWord = word[i].toCharArray();

            for(int j = 0; j < charWord.length; j++ ) {
            String cap = word[i].charAt(0) + "";
            cap = cap.toUpperCase();
            //System.out.print(" ");
            result += (j == 0 ? cap : word[i].charAt(j));
        }

        }

        return result;


      } 

      public static void main (String[] args) {  
        // keep this function call here     
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print(LetterCapitalize(s.nextLine())); 
      }   

   }
```

No errors. Just not getting desired output.

Comment: Your code isn't adding any spaces to the result.

Answer (score 1):

When you did `String[] word = str.split(" ");`, the space between each word is taken out and you are now left with only the words in an array. You should use `String.join(" ", word)` on the resultant words array to reverse the effects so you get the spaces back.

Instead of going through each word char by char, try this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    word[i] = word[i].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + word[i].substring(1);
}
result = String.join(" ", word);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {  
  public static String LetterCapitalize(String str) { 

    // code goes here   
    String[] word = str.split(" ");
    String result = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
        result += capitalize(word[i]) + (i != word.length - 1 ? " " : "");
    }

    return result;
  }

  private static String capitalize(String s){
      return Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(0)) + s.substring(1);
  }

  public static void main (String[] args) {  
    // keep this function call here     
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print(LetterCapitalize(s.nextLine())); 
  }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code.

```
class Main {
public static String LetterCapitalize(String str) {

    // code goes here
    String[] word = str.split(" ");
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();


    for (int i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {

        char[] charWord = word[i].toCharArray();

        for (int j = 0; j < charWord.length; j++) {
            String cap = word[i].charAt(0) + "";
            cap = cap.toUpperCase();
            //System.out.print(" ");
            result.append(j == 0 ? cap : word[i].charAt(j));
        }
        result.append(" ");
    }

    return result.toString();


}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // keep this function call here
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print(LetterCapitalize(s.nextLine()));
}
```

}

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. You can use the [edit] button to improve this answer to get more votes and reputation!